# Is $\mathbb{Q}[1]$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ring-isomorphism

If I am not mistaken, $\mathbb{Q}[1] \cong \mathbb{Q}/(f(X))$ denotes the ring of polynomials with rational coefficients evaluated in $1$ ($1$ being the root of the polynomial $f(X)$ as well).
Could we say that there exists an isomorphism such that $\mathbb{Q}[1] \cong \mathbb{Q}$? It seems to me that it's not impossible to express any fraction as a sum of fractions and vice-versa.
If such an isomorphism exists, what does it look like? And if not, why doesn't it exist?

Comment: Your first congruence should be $\mathbb{Q}[1]\cong\mathbb{Q}[X]/(f(X))$. Note that $f(x)$ is not any old polynomial: it's supposed to be an irreducible polynomial that has $1$ as a root, and that means that it is of the form $\alpha(X-1)$ for some rational $\alpha\neq 0$. The isomorphism sends an arbitrary polynomial $q(x)\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ to $q(1)$. I have no idea what "express[ing] any fraction as a fum of fractions and vice-versa" means here...

Comment: Not only an isomorphism, but an *equality* $\Bbb Q[1]=\Bbb Q$. Every rational is already a sum of rationals: namely, the sum with just one summand, itself. Conversely every sum of rationals is rational. In general, if $R$ is any (unital) ring and $\alpha\in R$ is any element, then $R[\alpha]=R$.

Comment: You're complicating it with the isomorphism to the quotient. They're simply equal since you're adjoining something already in the set.